# How to host a Blazor WASM app in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to host a Blazor WASM project within SharePoint online.
SharePoint programming is new to me, and apparently I am missing something here.

What I think I should do is:

1. Create the Blazor app
2. Create a SharePoint add-in with a web part.
3. Put the Web part on a SharePoint page.
4. Add a button to document libraries that will navigate to that page.

I am hoping that someone can confirm the above high level steps, and help me where I get stuck, at the bottom of the list below.

Steps performed so far:

1. Create the Blazor project. Done that, and it’s debugging fine at https://local:<port>
2. Add a SharePoint add-in project to my solution:

   1. Add > New Project... > SharePoint Add-in and give it a name.
   2. Provide the url of my developer site (that’s okay I think; it’s a developer site and supports sideloading) and select ‘Provider-hosted’ for ‘How do you want to host your SharePoint Add-in?’.
   3. Select ‘SharePoint Online’ for the earliest version of SharePoint to target.
   4. Select ‘ASP.NET Web Forms Application’ as web application project type (which is not relevant for my project as far as I can tell).
   5. Select ‘Use Windows Azure Access Control Service (for SharePoint cloud add-ins)’ for authentication.
3. Set The <name>AddIn, <name>AddInWeb and Blazor projects as the startup projects of my solution.
4. Add a web part to my AddIn project:

   1. Add > New Item... > Client Web Part (Host Web).
   2. Enter (for now) the localhost url for the Blazor project.
5. Start debugging so the add-in gets sideloaded on my development site.
   My Blazor app opens in a browser window and displays as expected and
   in another window the SharePoint host web gets redirected to the Default.aspx of my
   Host Web.
6. Open my development site in a new tab.
7. Add a page:

   1. Navigate to ‘Pages’ on the left nav menu.
   2. Select New > Web Part Page (not sure if this is the correct choice).
   3. Give it a name and select ‘Full Page, Vertical’ as the layout template.
   4. Leave the default of ‘Site Assets’ as the library to save the page.
   5. In the designer, click ‘Add a Web Part’ and select my web part (with a hexagon icon in front of it) and click ‘Add’.
   6. Here, I get a ’You Are Being Redirected To The Following URL That Was Not Registered As The App Launch Url’ warning.

I think I need to register the app using the appregnew.aspx for my tenant (so, not for the dev site).
I gave it a try, but the warning keeps appearing. When I click the ‘click here to preceed to the app now’ link in the warning, the web part seems to disappear, leaving only the page header.
Details entered when registering the app:

- Client Id and Client Secret: clicked ‘generate’
- Title: <name of my Blazor project>
- App Domain:   localhost:
- Redirect URI:     https://localhost:<port>/

Answer (score 0):

For a Blazor Wasm app, don't select Provider Hosted Add-in, but SharePoint Hosted Add-in.
There is (AFAIK) no way to tell the Wasm app what the Client ID and Client Secret, as described in the question, are.
In AppManifest.xml of the add-in, add the url of the Blazor app in the AllowedRemoteHostUrl attribute of the AppPrincipal/Internal element.